# How to add my custom phtml in home page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add my custom phtml to homepage.

I dont know how to add my phtml using my module

How can i add my phtml to homepage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add phtml like that

```
<cms_index_index translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="modulename/blockname" after="-" name="page_test" template="test/test.phtml"/>     
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this via admin side. For this :

1. Login into admin
2. Go to `CMS > Pages > Homepage`
3. Put the block directive inside content section like this :

   ```
   {{block type="modulename/blockname" name="custom.template" template="path/to/your/template"}}
   ```

You are done.

Comment: My custom feedback module: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0  how can i add into all pages including the home page.

Answer (score 1):

### I have another solution.

- **Goto admin**
- **then GO to Cms > Page**
- **Select your home Page**
- **Then goto it Design tab**
- **Now put your layout code at field Layout Update XML field**

> `<reference name="content">
>           <block type="BlockPrefix/blockname"  template="TemplateFolder/templateName.phtml"/>
>
>       </reference>`

Here i have set `templateName.phtml` template ***at content area of layout***