# Configure homepage to use phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento. I am using version 1.9.1. How can i call a phtml page as home page?

So far im making changes in cms->homepage->design im changing the html code there.
But now i want to include php in the homepage src code. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple, don't need to develop extension for it.

Just go to your home page (cms page) and add this line anywhere you like:

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/your_path/file_name.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

However, it will depend what kind of info you will be adding in this file.

Comment: I have to include this in cms->homepage->design only ryt?

Comment: this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could go by module way.

Create your module's xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Page />
      </depends>
    </Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
  </modules>
</config>
```

And then the config.xml file should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Yourcompany_Yourmodule>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <page>
      <layouts>
        <yourmodule translate="label">
          <label>Yourcompany_Yourmodule</label>
          <template>page/homepage.phtml</template>
          <layout_handle>home_page</layout_handle>
        </yourmodule>
        <!-- add more layouts here -->
      </layouts>
    </page>
  </global>
</config>
```

Now add to your CMS Page and edit.

Now go to your Magento back end admin. Go to CMS > Pages.

Now go to the CMS homepage, you should now have `Home_page` in your `layout` dropdown select it and save your page.

Now go back to your homepage.phtml and edit till your hearts content!

Refer below for more understanding.

http://naileditdesign.com/creating-custom-homepage-template-magento/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the file like below.
go to `CMS->Pages` and **select Homepage**.

Add following line to `Content`.

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/your_path/file_name.phtml"  name="your_name"}}
```

Ensure your path Correctly.

If you want to add some specific category only in home page.
Use below code.Give the relevant category on `category_id`.

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

In the design choose appropriate `layout` for your home page.

You can find some more answer from this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88777/how-to-add-my-custom-phtml-in-home-page) for the same type of task

Comment: yes its working now.... But im getting it like iframe format? I am using rwd default theme but i can configure only from base/default/cms/default/home? If i use rwd/default/template its not working?

Comment: What is the layout u used?

Comment: 2column with right bar..